# Python: Turtle can't call function twice

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I have a question, I was trying to draw a square and a circle in Python (2.7) using the turtle module.

```
import turtle
def draw_cricle(circle_size):

    boby = turtle.Turtle()

    boby.color("black")
    boby.shape("arrow")

    boby.right(90)
    boby.forward(200)
    boby.left(90)
    boby.back(20)

    boby.circle(circle_size)

def draw_square(forward_dst, right_angle):
    window = turtle.Screen()

    window.bgcolor("red")
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("circle")
    brad.speed(3)

    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)
    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)
    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)
    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)
    window.exitonclick()

draw_square(100,90)

draw_cricle(100)
```

My problem is that I can't call the the draw_circle function after calling the draw_square function.

And yes I know I should have used a loop in draw_square

Comment: What do you mean "I can't call the draw_circle function"? what happens when you try?

Comment: When I executed the program only the first function would be executed. 
But I have got an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the window when running window.exitonclick() from the `draw_square` function. You should define the window outside of these functions if you want to use the same window to draw both square and circle, otherwise, you're closing the window before even starting to draw a circle.

```
import turtle


def draw_cricle(circle_size):

    boby = turtle.Turtle()

    boby.color("black")
    boby.shape("arrow")

    boby.right(90)
    boby.forward(200)
    boby.left(90)
    boby.back(20)

    boby.circle(circle_size)

def draw_square(forward_dst, right_angle):

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("circle")
    brad.speed(3)

    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)
    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)
    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)
    brad.forward(forward_dst)
    brad.right(right_angle)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")

draw_square(100,90)
draw_cricle(100)


window.exitonclick()
```